# java generics subtype in interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

If I have the following interface and I want to implement it

```
public interface A<E extends Comparable<E>>{
    //code
}
```

What is the correct syntax for the implementing class declaration? I get an error when I do this

```
public class B<E extends Comparable<E>> implements A<E extends Comparable<E>>{}
```

Should it just read `implements A<E>` or just `implements A`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where the `Comparable` type `E` is, for example, `String`, you would want:

```
public class B implements A<String> { ... }
```

Where you want to retain the generic type parameter declaration in `B`, you would have:

```
public static class B<E extends Comparable<E>> implements A<E> { ... }
```

Note that the `E` in `A` is not related to the `E` in `B`, i.e. the following is valid:

```
public static class B<Foo extends Comparable<Foo>> implements A<Foo> { ... }
```

(whether you want to distinguish or not in your code I don't know, but it might help in understanding)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class B<E extends Comparable<E>> implements A<E>{}
```

Comment: I think so too. You have to redeclare that this E is really a Comparable, before you can give it to your interface.